# Command not working when mapped

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, terminal, startup

I've mapped <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to `:split | resize 15 | term`. This command works when run from Vim, but when I put the command in my `.vimrc`, on Vim startup, I get the following error:

```
zsh:1: parse error near '>'

[Process exited 1]
```

When removing the mapping, Vim starts normally.

Comment: What exactly did you put in your vimrc? I think you probably want to use `<Bar>` instead of `|` in your mapping? See `:help map-bar`

Comment: Adding `<Bar>` instead of `|` worked, thank you! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! @MartinTournoij good catch, though I’m at a loss on zsh’s error (unless it’s launching term with the contents of vimrc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> What exactly did you put in your vimrc? I think you probably want to use `<Bar>` instead of `|` in your mapping. See `:help map-bar`.